# Trying to download 14.04 LTS Desktop with Down Them All in Firefox

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

This is taking forever to download, is this normal.  I have downloaded many Linux distributions and never seen one this slow.  Could be my connection but never had an issue yet!  This is from the official site.  I just cancelled download, life is to short, that's why I don't bother much with Windows.  Any help would be appreciated.  I'm not blaming Ubuntu.com just frustrated, needed it today.

Comment: Have you tried downloading with a torrent client?

Answer (score 0):

[Alternative downloads](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads)

There are several other ways to get Ubuntu including torrents, which can potentially mean a quicker downloads, the network installer for older systems and special configurations, and links to the regional DVD image mirrors for older (and newer) releases are also available.

Comment: I answered my own question shortly after I posted here, but it did not take.  Is it that I cannot answer my own questions?

Comment: Thank you for asking gave me a chance to answer. Cheers!

Comment: Thompson Dawes, What?